# how to make richtextbox in vb same size as A4 paper

Tags: vb.net

i need to know how to make a richtextbox in vb 2008 express edition the same size as a piece of A4 paper,  i want to make my editing program as close to open office or Microsoft word as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Horizontal size = (8.27in)  x (300 pixels/in) = 2481
Vertical size   = (11.69in) x (300 pixels/in) = 3507

Horizontal size = ((210mm) / (25.4mm/in)) x (300 pixels/in) = 2480.3150 ≅ 2481
Vertical size   = ((297mm) / (25.4mm/in)) x (300 pixels/in) = 3507.8740 ≅ 3508

Precise measurements can be found in this answer here https://superuser.com/a/480198

Simply set your richtextbox to match at the right resolution